# Do Edit or Delete Action in table With Dynamic ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I encountered some problem to identify dynamic ID in table that have dynamic IDs to do some action like edit or delete, because the IDs is dynamic shown, I don't understand how to do action like edit data from code no 12345 when shown id is id=...0.
How to solving this? I'm using Selenium IDE. How we can 
do edit or delete when the number id is dynamic?
Here is the HTML code

```
<div>
<table id="gvSomething" class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            <a id="CODE">code no.</a>
        <th scope="col">
            <a id="NAME">name</a>
        <th scope="col">
            <a id="STATUS">active</a>
        <th scope="col"> CONTROL </th>
    </tr>    

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span id="Code_0">12345</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="Name_0">zero</span>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <span id="Status_0">Yes</span>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <input id="Edit_0" type="image" src="../Images/Edit.gif" title="Edit Record" name="Status$ctl02$imbEdit">
            <input id="Delete_0" type="image" src="../Images/Delete.gif" title="Delete Record" name="Delete$ctl02$imbDelete">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <span id="Code_1">098765</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="Name_1">one</span>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <span id="Status_1">Yes</span>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center">
            <input id="Edit_1" type="image" src="../Images/Edit.gif" title="Edit Record" name="Status$ctl03$imbEdit">
            <input id="Delete_1" type="image" src="../Images/Delete.gif" title="Delete Record" name="Delete$ctl03$imbDelete">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the sample code when data not yet added with new data

```
code                |   name            | active            |    control

12345 (id=Code_1)     zero (id=name_1)   yes (id=status_1)      edit(id=edit_1)/delete (id=delete_1) 

098765 (id=Code_2)    one (id=name_2)    yes (id=status_2)      edit(id=edit_2)/delete (id=delete_2)
```

and when there's new data added, become like this

```
code                |   name            | active            |    control

01234 (id=Code_1)     new (id=name_1)    yes (id=status_1)      edit(id=edit_1)/delete (id=delete_1) 

12345 (id=Code_2)     zero (id=name_2)   yes (id=status_2)      edit(id=edit_2)/delete (id=delete_2) 

098765 (id=Code_3)    one (id=name_3)    yes (id=status_3)      edit(id=edit_3)/delete (id=delete_3)
```

How selenium IDE know when we try to click edit image with id=edit_2 it know we want to edit data with name 12345 and name zero, not edit data with name 09876?

Comment: I don't understand - is `12345` the number you want to get? Is `Code_0` the "dynamic ID" you talk about? Also, is the position of the number you want, always constant in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, Code_0 is the dynamic ID, and the second row is Code_1 and so on.
What i don't understand is how come Selenium understand if when we select EDIT with id Edit_1 it know to edit data which its ID is 098765 and name one.

Because when I tried to add row, example, id=090909 name=new name, this new data have edit image id Edit_1 and Delete_1.

So how to solve this problem?
Thx

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand what you are saying. Can you please edit your question (not the comment) and say exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: Done, something like that..

Answer (score 0):

For things like dynamic tables, ID locators won't do the job, you're right. However Selenium has two types of locators for finding elements relative to other elements: XPath and CSS selectors. CSS selectors are usually recommended because they are faster, but since we are looking at text and not HTML tag attributes, XPath is the way to go for this problem.

Below is a locator you could use as the locator in selenium IDE if you wanted to find a row that contained the code no. 12345 and the name zero, then select the edit control in that row.

```
xpath=//tr[contains(., "12345") and contains(., "zero")]//input[contains(@id, "Edit")]
```

Here is [W3school's tutorial on XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) and [reference on CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)